# Redux state is not uniform across all tabs

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Im facing an issue now with my authentication system that is based on `django-simplejwt` and `redux-saga`.

Whenever i click on the log out button , the following saga is run:

```
export function* workerLogout(action) {
    const r_token = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
    yield call(() => axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/blacklist/', {
            "refresh_token": r_token
        }))             //<--- API end-point to blacklist the tokens
    localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
    localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token'); // <--- removing the tokens
    yield call(() =>  axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = null  ); //<--- setting the headers to null
    yield put({ type: "LOGOUT_SUCCESS" }) //<---- This will go to the reducer to set the states to null
    
}
```

Which will then acccess the reducer here:

```
const authLogout = (state, action) => {
return updateObject(state, {
    access_token: null,
    refresh_token: null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
    group: {},
    username: null,
});
```

}

This works and my redux tool bar shows that the state of the tab is indeed cleared:

```
isAuthenticated(pin):false
access_token(pin):null
refresh_token(pin):null
group(pin):
username(pin):null
```

My interceptor:

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
response => {
    return response
},async error => {
    const originalRequest = error.config;
    // Prevent infinite loops
    if (error.response.status === 401 && originalRequest.url === '/token/refresh/') {
        store.dispatch({type: "LOGOUT"});
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
    
    if (error.response.data.code === "token_not_valid" &&
        error.response.status === 401 && 
        error.response.statusText === "Unauthorized") 
        {   
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken){
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    console.log('access token is expired , attempting refresh')
                    try {
                        const response = await axiosInstance
                            .post('/token/refresh/', { refresh: refreshToken });
                        localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);
                        axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + response.data.access;
                        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + response.data.access;
                        axiosInstance.get('group/get/').then(groups => {
                            store.dispatch({type: "LOGIN_SUCCESS" ,  payload:[response.data.access, refreshToken, groups.data, jwt_decode(response.data.access).username]});
                        })
                        return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                    }
                    catch (err) {
                        store.dispatch({type: "GET_ERRORS" , error : err.response.data})
                    }
                }else{
                    store.dispatch({type: "LOGOUT"});
                }
            }
    }
    store.dispatch({type: "GET_ERRORS" , error : error.response.data})
return Promise.reject(error);
  }

    );
```

However , if let's say a second tab was open at the point of the logout , i can still access my server's resources from the second tab. Upon closer inspection of the redux tool bar , it seems the state of the second tab is not affected by the first tab.

Is this an expected behavior? If so how do i make it in synced across all tabs as this seems like a bad way to secure the application.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to store your Accesstoken and refreshtoken in Browser's local storage. Clearing accesstoken from redux store will not impact the other tabs.

On your Login success you can store accesstoken as

```
static saveToken(token, refreshToken){
 window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
 window.localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', refreshToken);
}
```

On your logout success you can just remove the token by

```
static clearAccessToken(){
  window.localStorage.removeItem('token');
  window.localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
}
```

In your request Interceptor you can access the accesstoken/refreshtoken by

```
static isAuthenticated(){
 return window.localStorage.token != null;
}

static getAccessToken(){
 return window.localStorage.token;
}

static getRefreshToken(){
 return window.localStorage.refresh_token;
}
```

By doing this way when you logout from one tab it will logged out from your browser.

You can contorl the logout error in authInterceptor

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
  return response
}, (error) => {

  const { config, response: { status } } = error;
  const originalRequest = config;

  if (status === 401) {
    if(config.url.endsWith('oauth/token') || config.url.endsWith('users/logout')){
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }


    if (!this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken) {
      this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = true;
      var refreshTokenValue = AuthService.getRefreshToken();

      refreshToken(refreshTokenValue).then((token) => {
        this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false

        if(token && token.data && token.data.access_token){
          AuthService.saveToken(token.data.access_token, token.data.refresh_token);
          this.onAccessTokenFetched(token.data.access_token);
        }
      }).catch(err => {
        this.isAlreadyFetchingAccessToken = false;
        this.subscribers = [];
        
        this.history.push('/login');
        return Promise.reject("Auth error");
      })
    }

    const retryOriginalRequest = new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.addSubscriber(access_token => {
        originalRequest.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + access_token
        resolve(axios(originalRequest))
      })
    })

    return retryOriginalRequest
  }


  console.log("Unknown error :" + error);
  
  let errorMessage = '';

  if(error.response && error.response.data) {
    return Promise.reject(error.response.data);
  } else {    
    return Promise.reject({
      code: UNKNOWN_ERROR,
      message: "Oops, Unable to complete the request"
    });
  }
})
```

This is my request interceptor

```
 axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  if(AuthService.isAuthenticated()){
    if(config.url.startsWith(apiUrl) && !config.url.startsWith(OAUTH_URL)){
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.token;
   }
  }
  return config;
});
```

In the above code I am reading my access token directly from localstorage. Upon logout the Authorization header by default becomes invalid and throws 401 now In your reponse interceptor you can redirect to logout page when refresh token fails. Hope this will help.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the reply ,  I see , so this is actually an expected behavior. However , its weird in the sense that i actually set the axiosInstance default headers to null on the first tab , but this is not transmitted to the second tab. Is this an expected behavior as well?

Comment: You dont have set axios header manually, If you are reading the access token from local storage on logout next server call will throw 401 then you can call refreshtoken api that will also throw an error. you can redirect your page to logout. I will update my answer with auth Interceptor code.

Comment: Hey , thanks for your time appreciate it. I have decided to just cause the page to reload using window.location.reload() if it fails the check for a token in the storage. This will then cause all of the states to be updated and redirect to the login page

Comment: Instead of reloading the page. I'd suggest you to pass the {history} to your auth Interceptor and redirect to logout page.

Comment: Hey , sorry for asking that many questions. Im having troubles with passing {history} into the interceptor , on top of that , i found out that if i had 3 tabs open in my browser , the localstorage seems not to be in synced.

Comment: for the later , i realize it was because the third tab was run on 127... instead of localhost , however im still facing some troubles with passing the history to the interceptor

Comment: For that you have to create history using createBrowserHistory(); then you can pass it to authInterceptor as a parameter.